# Effect on other window drive while install ubuntu on windows 7?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, windows-7, window

I want to install Ubuntu alongside with my window 7. Currently i have 6 partition with window 7 as C:, D:, E:, F:, G: and H:. My window file reside in C: drive.

What will be the effect on other drives if i install Ubuntu alongside with window install? What will be the effect on data contained in other drives?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As long as each drive as its minimum required amount of free space to operate, then nothing will happen. The data will remain safe as well, each drive is a separate container for data. The only issue you could run into is if the drives become too small after the additional Ubuntu drive.

Some additional info: http://www.tomshardware.com/forum/7832-45-minimum-hard-drive-space-needed

Comment: if i intall ubuntu in C drive then is there effect on other drives(D, E, F etc.).

Comment: Nope, only C will be erased to make Ubuntu. The only potential issue is choosing the wrong drive because Ubuntu does not recognize Windows drives. You'll see /dev/sda1 instead of E or F.

Comment: Can i install ubuntu on a separate drive?

Comment: Yes, in the installer you have the option of creating an additional partition.